# Add input values to table - Angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I input file name in table for each time when I import some file?

I have input and button that actualy start event on that input on click.

`<button class="btn-main" (click)="ElementFileInput.click()">Import </button>
<input #ElementFileInput (change)="importElement($event)" type="file" " style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;" />`

Also, in my ts I have defined that function, and extracted name value from file.

TS function:

```
importElement(event: any) {

    this.values = event.target.files[0].name;
```

And html part where I show my file name:

```
<label style="color: blue">{{values}}</label>
```

Function is working and when I input file, i get name written in label.

But I want to make table that will list file names for every file that I import, not just once. How can I do that?

Comment: will this list of files be available on refresh coz if yes u'll need some kind of storage

Comment: I plan to user array to store files, but since that this component is actualy a popup modal, refresh will erase all data anyway ;) I need array solution just for that case when user import files in one take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a member variable in your component class to push the values to:

```ts
files: Array<string> = [];
```

And in your import method just call `push` on the array:

```ts
importSeabed(event: any) {

    this.files.push(event.target.files[0].name);
```

This way the file name will be added to the array instead of replacing your variable.

To display the list you need the `ngFor` directive:

```html
<label style="color: blue" *ngFor="let file of files">{{file}}</label>
```

Comment: Great, that is just what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `importSeabed()` function could add the file name to an array each time it is executed. You could then use the `*ngFor` expression within your component's template to add a new table element for each value within the array.

See [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor) for further information.